# ¿porqué se incrementa un post operador si llega una exception?

Tags: java, excepciones

```
     try{        
                clientes[indiceClientes++]=fabricarCliente(); 
                                           
        }
                                       
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

De fabricarClientes(); puede llegar un objeto cliente bien construido o una excepción propagada.

Si llega el objeto  se asigna al array el objeto y luego se incrementa el índice.
Si llega una excepción , no hay asignación. La excepción es capturada en el catch pero el índice aumenta.

Porqué aumenta el índice si se supone que la secuencia del código debiera haberse interrumpido?

Comment: Se debe a la precendencia de los operadores, el operador de post incremento `++` tiene una precedencia más alta que el de asignación `=` por esa razón se evalúa antes de llamar a la función. Tabla de precedencia: http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html

Comment: Gracias, mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque de igual forma estas incrementando el índice `clientes[indiceClientes++]=fabricarCliente();`, aunque el flujo se interrumpa por el error, para ese momento el índice ya ha sido incrementado.